# Can Heroku logs be downloaded via the web, or other non-CLI method?

Tags: logging, heroku

I'm trying to read my Heroku logs, but I'm away from my laptop where I have Heroku installed; otherwise I'd use

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Is there a way that I can get to the logs from the website?  Or maybe pull them via some kind of authenticated REST call to Heroku's server?

Comment: You can look into a log drains https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains or it might be easier just to setup Papertrail and use the free version https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail

Comment: @ConorF just installed Papertrail--see my comment on Stan Mazhara's answer.

Comment: ahh, yeah as @stan stated they only allow up to a `maximum of 1500` lines of history with their logs. You could possibly reach out to Heroku support but my bet would they would say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Heroku does not provide log storage. Their 'Logplex is designed for collating and routing log messages, not for storage.' (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits)

You can, however, use Heroku addons. Find them here https://elements.heroku.com/addons - click 'Logging' in ADD-ONS CATEGORIES. Many of them have free tiers. Installation is as simple as `heroku addons:add logentries:le_tryit` (free Logentries tier example).

You can also roll your own service by configuring their Log Drains (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains).

Comment: Yes, I just installed the Papertrail add-on.  Unfortunately, it will only accumulate future log entries, and so I can't use it to access my most recent 1500 lines of logging before this evening, which is what I was hoping to accomplish.